# Change Keyboard Language In iOS App When Click In UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextfield

i tried many ways to change keyboard in ipad programmatically but it doesn't change at all .
i cant find any property in uitext for doing this.

any idea?

Comment: You mind letting us know what are those "many ways" you tried?

Comment: something like: '[textField setAccessibilityLanguage:@"English"];'
without error but, no actiion :-??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot control the language of the keyboard. The user chooses which keyboards they would like available via the settings application and can toggle between them using the globe icon on the keyboard. When the keyboard is opened it will open to the most recently used keyboard.

Here is what you need my friend,

```
[textView setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];

[txtField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
```

Comment: i don't want it for text,i want to get numbers in english (standard type) so there is no way to do it?

Comment: Do you want to make the keyboard a numbers keyboard, what you mean by "standard type" ?!

Comment: when keyboard changes to another language  (like arabic or Farsi) numbers change too, and u cant save them in db or use them in your code like standard digits. so i need to change the keyboard to EN when user wants to enter numbers.

Comment: Do you want just Numeric keyboard?

Comment: it doesn't change language at all but i figured out numbers between languages can set to standard digits by xcode ,so i don't need to change language any more. however i think it's a really important bug in iOS!