# Is there any way to add a language to user system settings in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I am working on localizing my iOS application. Done with the whole process But there's an issue with the keyboard, I am providing a functionality for user to change the language from inside the app (System, English and Hindi).

However, the issue I am facing is with the keyboard. I managed to open the keyboard as per the user language but if user doesn't have Hindi added in keyboard languages in system settings it opens english keyboard.

Is there any way I can programatically add Hindi to keyboard languages in the user settings?

I am using following code in UITextField, UITextView subclass for setting keyboard langauge:

```
override open var textInputMode: UITextInputMode?{
    let language = LanguageManager.shared.getCurrentLocale()?.languageCode ?? ""
    if language == "" {
        return super.textInputMode
    } else {
        for tim in UITextInputMode.activeInputModes {
            if tim.primaryLanguage!.contains(language) {
                return tim
            }
        }
        return super.textInputMode
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Keyboard Language In iOS App When Click In UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319706/change-keyboard-language-in-ios-app-when-click-in-uitextfield)

Comment: @IvanSmetanin : It's not duplicate, the link you posted says the user wants to change the keyboard, but I want to add a new language to keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. Because only user can control keyboard language. Developer can change `UIKeyboardType` (e.g `emailAddress`, `numberPad`).

Comment: But you can detect if a given keyboard has been installed by the user or not and if not, show an alert suggesting the user runs Settings and install the keyboard.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. I think I have to show user a popup that the language he/she selected isn't present in the keyboard. So, he/she has to goto system setting and add the language to the keyboard.